# Creating and assigning data to a JavaFX line chart object in one class and passing it to another class produces no graph

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having an issue that has been bugging me for the past few weeks. I've got two classes; DataDisplay and DashboardController. Some of their contents are shown below:

**DashboardController**

```
@FXML
private LineChart<Date, Number> lnChart;

@FXML
private NumberAxis numAxis;

@FXML
private DateAxis dateAx;

@FXML
private Gauge dialTemp, dialHumidity, dialPressure;

@FXML
private VBox vbxDialTemp, vbxDialHumidity, vbxDialPressure;

@FXML
private GridPane grdPneDial;

......

@FXML
private void graphAllOptionAction (ActionEvent event)
{
    if (dateHasBeenSet == true)
    {
        DataDisplay dd = new DataDisplay();
        lnChart = dd.graphAll(dateFrom, dateTo);
    }
    else
    {
        txaErrors.setText("Please select a date range!");
    }
}
```

**DataDisplay**

```
public LineChart graphAll (Date dateFrom, Date dateTo)
{
    LineChart<Date, Number> lnChart = new LineChart<>(dateAx, numAxis);
    try
    {
        lnChart.setTitle("All Sensory Data");
        XYChart.Series tempSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series humiditySeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series windSpeedSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series pressureSeries = new XYChart.Series<>();

        tempSeries.setName("Temperature");
        humiditySeries.setName("Humidity");
        windSpeedSeries.setName("Wind Speed (m/s)");
        pressureSeries.setName("Pressure (hPa)");

        lnChart.getData().clear();

        SensorArr sa = new SensorArr(dateFrom, dateTo);

        for (int i = 0; i < sa.getNumberOfEntries(); i = i + 8)
        {
            tempSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("" + sa.getDate(i), sa.getTemp(i)));
            humiditySeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("" + sa.getDate(i), sa.getHumidity(i)));
            windSpeedSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("" + sa.getDate(i), sa.getWindspeed(i)));
            pressureSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("" + sa.getDate(i), sa.getPressure(i)));
        }

        lnChart.getData().add(tempSeries);
        lnChart.getData().add(humiditySeries);
        lnChart.getData().add(windSpeedSeries);
        lnChart.getData().add(pressureSeries);

        lnChart.setVisible(true);

        return lnChart;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return lnChart;
}
```

Now when I run my project and select the Graph All button on my gui, the [graph is not displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB3RZ.png)

But when I move the code from the DataDisplay method back into the DashboardController class, the [graph is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62blo.png)

Does anybody know a solution to this problem. To me it seems like its a simple fix but I just can't fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: You create a new chart (`lnChart = dd.graphAll(...)`, and `graphAll()` does `lnChart = new LineChart<>(...)`) but never do anything with it... You need to display it in the UI somewhere. Alternatively, pass an existing chart to the `graphAll(...)` method, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that. You're a life saver :-)